# Wavelet transform using dwt3 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, dwt

I have a project to transform an image using `dwt`.
I successfully done it using function `dwt2`, and now I try to use function `dwt3` by changes some code from the function `dwt2` (add more subband: 8 subbands). Unfortunately, an error comes out, which said "Too many output arguments".

My question is, what is the right way to write MATLAB code for `dwt3`? Is it not same as `dwt2`, just add more subbands?

Answer (score 1):

Just by looking at the official documentation for [`dwt2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/wavelet/ref/dwt2.html) and [`dwt3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/wavelet/ref/dwt3.html), I see that `dtw3` has only 1 output variable, whereas `dtw2` has 4.

I assume you just replaced the string `dtw2` in your code to `dwt3`, without paying attention to the amount of allowed output variables. So there you go, that's where the error *"too many output variables"* comes from...

If `dwt3` only returns the transformed vector, cut the number of output variables to 1, and I'm sure the error will away:

```
Y = dwt3(X, 'db2');
```

Here I transformed `X` using `dwt3` with the Daubechies 2-tap wavelet, and stored the result in `Y`.

P.S
You need to show more code if you want more productive, helpful answers...